# How to create form field for every foreign key in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to build a form and I am not sure how this should be done correctly. These are my models:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    twocode = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)

class GeoBonus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='geo_bonuses')
    bookmaker = models.ForeignKey(Bookmaker, related_name='geo_bonuses')
```

Bookmaker has bonuses, different for each country. For example:

```
Bookmaker has bonuses:
    Slovakia: "eligible for 100% up to $200"
    Afghanistan: "eligible for 100% up to €100!"
    USA: "restricted country"
    ...
```

And I want to save text in quotes as `name` in GeoBonus. Of course I can write use simple model form, but I would have submit form 248 time(for each country). I would like to show all fields for each country.

- If `name` is blank, GeoBonus will not be created.
- If `name` is not blank, create GeoBonus object.
  This is what it should look like:
  [image: GeoBonus form bootstrap]
  How code in **forms.py** and **views.py** will look like? I also need to **edit** fields.

---

I tried to manually create new fields for countries:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="wide">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {%bootstrap_form form %}
        <div class="form-group">
        {%for country in countries%}
        <label class="control-label" for="{{country.twocode}}">{{country}}</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="{{country.twocode}}" maxlength="250" type="text" />
        {%endfor%}
        </div>
        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
```

Using this forms.py class:

```
class GeoBonusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GeoBonus
        fields = ['bookmaker']
```

But `request.POST` does contain only bookmaker field.

EDIT1: Views.py

```
@staff_member_required
def geo_bonus_edit(request, bookmaker=None):
    template = loader.get_template('geobonus/edit.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GeoBonusForm(request.POST)
        print request.POST
    else:
        form = GeoBonusForm()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': GeoBonusForm,
        'countries': Country.objects.all(),
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the view delivering the template?

Comment: @RodrigoDela I do not have much view code at the moment, not sure how this should be done. But view added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest, that you generate the fields in your form dynamically. It could look like this:

```
class GeoBonusForm(forms.ModelForm):
    countries = Country.objects.all()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GeoBonusForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for country in self.countries:
            self.fields[country.name] = forms.CharField()
```

This allows you to generate a CharField for every Country you have.
Therefore the saving is a bit different than the normal ModelForm would expect it I would recommend to override the `save` method:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    super(GeoBonusForm, self).save(commit=False)
    bookmaker = Bookmaker.objects.get(id=self.cleaned_data['bookmaker'].id)
    for field in self.cleaned_data:
        if field != 'bookmaker':
            country = Country.objects.get(name=field)
            geo_bonus, created = GeoBonus.objects.get_or_create(bookmaker=bookmaker, country=country)
            geo_bonus.name = self.cleaned_data[field]
            geo_bonus.save()
```

At first we try to get the chosen bookmaker. After that we iterate over the cleaned fields (for more about form cleaning take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)) and try to `get_or_create` the `GeoBonus` object. Now we just fill in the value of the corresponding `country` field and save.

I adapted the code of your view a little bit:

```
def index(request, bookmaker=None):
    template = loader.get_template('geobonus/edit.html')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = GeoBonusForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = GeoBonusForm()
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': GeoBonusForm,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

You don't need to pass the countries to the context anymore, because we generate the field in the form. On `POST` we check if the form is valid and save it, if it is.

For the template you only should only need this now:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Hope I got it right and that this solves your problem.

Edit: Note, that this is a simple quick example. Of course you should clean the data and check if the input is valid and maybe prepare it for a more simple saving process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Django's [inlinemodelformset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) for that, refer to [using a formset in views and templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates) for example code.

Comment: hmm, formset afaik is used to print multiple modelforms. But I need to print one modelform for 250 foreingkeys (country).

Comment: Then you could use [Inline model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), answer updated.